# How I handle bindkey in zsh?

Tags: linux, zsh, key-binding

There is not a lot of info on that command, I didn't find a manpage nor a info and not more than examples on the web. Is there any tutorial or info on internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
man zshzle | less -p '^ZLE BUILTINS'
```

On the Web: [Zle Builtins](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins)

From the ZshWiki site: [Zle](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/start) (Note the navigation on the left. There are a few sub items.)

And my favorite fallback option (or to see examples), [how other people do it](http://google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+zshrc+bindkey).

Answer (score 1):

`bindkey` is a builtin and should be described in the manual of zsh. Try also "`help bindkey`".

Comment: it didn't work for me